# If... else versus if.... else if

Tags: r, if-statement

I am working through an assignment and I am confused about what the question is asking/allowing me to use. 
DATA
AMD "Return is 5%"
GE "Return is 1%
Anything else "Not in your portfolio"

The instructions state to use if... else for part A and to use if... else if for part B
Here is my code for reference

## Part A

```
mystock <- "GE"
if (mystock == "AMD")
  {print ("Return is 5%")} else (mystock == "GE")
{print ("Return is 1%")}
```

## Part B

```
mystock <- "GE"

if (mystock == "AMD") {print ("Return is 5%")} 
else if (mystock == "GE") {
      print ("My return is 1%")} 
else if(mystock != "AMD") {
      print ("Not in your portfolio")} 
else if (mystock != "GE") {
      print ("Not in your portfolio")}
```

I think Part B is correct per instructions, I am not sure how to add a third arguement into Part A and still be compliant with instructions.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Do you need `if (mystock == "AMD") {print ("Return is 5%")} else if (mystock == "GE") {print ("My return is 1%")} else print("Not in your portfolio")`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mystock == "AMD") {
  print ("Return is 5%") } 
else if (mystock == "GE") {
  print ("My return is 1%") } 
else {
  print ("Not in your portfolio") }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to your `if-else` structure is `switch`, i.e.,

```
switch (mystock,
  "AMD" = print ("Return is 5%"),
  "GE" = print("My return is 1%"),
  print("Not in your portfolio")
)
```